# Some help on a Union LINQ expression please

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I need some help constructing a LINQ expression. I tend to use Lambda syntax.

I have 2 tables

```
OrderItem >- LibraryItem
```

OrderItem has a number of columns:

```
Id
FkLibraryItemId
Text
FkOrderId
```

LibraryItem has a number of Columns:

```
Id
Text
Type
```

Usually when selecting an "OrderItem", one picks a "Library Item". The "Id" and "Text" value are placed into the item record.

Sometimes a user may add a one off "OrderItem" which does not need storing in the "LibraryItem" table. It is simply stored in "OrderItem", but without a "FkLibraryItemId". So I have records in "OrderItem" that do not exist in "LibraryItem".

I need the LINQ to pull out all the relevant "LibraryItem" records of "Type=X" in addition to the "OrderItem" records for the relevant Order Id.

Many thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I think I am talking about something like:

```
LibraryItem.Select(new{Id,Text}).Union(Order.Select(new{Id, Text})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    context.OrderItems.Include("LibraryItems")
.Where(o => o.OrderId == orderId 
&&(o.LibraryItem != null ? o.LibraryItem.Type == "X" : true))
```

Linq-to-SQL has a different syntax for `Include`, which basically eager-loads the reference objects (probably `LoadWith`, I don't remember at the moment).

Actually you can also do it with left inner join.

Comment: Will "Include" just reflect those records that are referenced with FKs. What about those that are not? Oh and a big thank you for the help.

Comment: It'll populate the foreign key objects, if there is a null FK, it'll just bring the main object. Ah I think, I got it wrong, let me rewrite the query

Comment: Thanks for this. Just realised that I am using a <list> and one cannot use "Include" with lists, or maybe it is possible somehow.

Comment: If you're using List, you've already executed the query, may be you should do the Include before you bring the List from database.

Comment: Thank you for this. You got me thinking on a different plane.